# Quick Ripple Effect Puzzle: $70$ Empty Cells

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[image]

> **Ripple Effect** (taken from [Nikoli](https://www.nikoli.co.jp/en/puzzles/ripple_effect.html))
>
> - The areas divided by bold lines are called "rooms". Fill in all empty cells with numbers under the following rules.
> - Each room contains consecutive numbers starting from 1 (to $n$ where $n$ is the area of the room).
> - If a number is duplicated in a row or a column, the space between the duplicated numbers must be equal to or larger than the value of the number.

Comment: Just to clarify: the "space between" means the number of cells between, not counting either end? So `1 2 1` is possible but `1 1` isn't?

Comment: @Randal'Thor that's correct

Comment: Is this your puzzle or from somewhere else? I just have the slightest inkling I’ve seen it somewhere…

Comment: @boboquack this is my own puzzle, if you had seen this before I guess a participant of a local competition KPK is sharing it. (So yeah, this is one of the puzzles the competition I authored.)

Comment: @athin Nice! __

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Final solution

> [image]

### Step by step

- > First fill in the two single-cell rooms with 1. Consider the left-hand one of these, and the two-cell room near it. If 1 is on the right of that two-cell room, then 1 can't be anywhere in the tetromino between. So we fill that two-cell room with `1 2`. Then there's only one possible place for 2 in that tetromino between.
  >
  >  [image]
- > In the next zigzag tetromino to the left, we can see which cells must be 3,4 and which must be 1,2. In the triomino above, 2 can't be at the top. That tells us where the 1 and 2 are in that tetromino, and then we can fill in that whole triomino and the top left domino.
  >
  >  [image]
- > Now it's easy to fill in the rest of the three half-filled tetrominoes, and some stray 2s and 3s around the place:
  >
  >  [image]
- > And then the rest of the left-hand side:
  >
  >  [image]
- > And the rest goes smoothly to the end. (Let me know if I should add more details here, but I've shown now how the deductions work, and once half the grid is filled the rest becomes relatively easy.)

Answer (score 9):

> [image]

I like this game. I hope this solution can help.

Comment: You got the first :-) Nice first answer!

Comment: Thanks but I didn't provide step-by-step pictures like you did

Comment: Could you put your solution in a spoiler block, please?

Comment: I'm going to accept @Randal'Thor solution as it is more comprehensive, but +1 for fast solving! :D

Comment: (sorry, "the" should be "there" in my first comment - too late to correct)

Answer (score -1):

So I got a different answer than the accepted one, I assume that means I made a mistake somewhere. Can anyone help me spot it?

> [image: Wrong solution to the puzzle]

Comment: In the third row, the gap between the second 4 and the third 4 is just two.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I guess I will have to re-do it.